# Google Map nearby API is not working in ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I post the below API:

```
let str11 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"
```

with below parameters:

```
params = ["location":"-33.8670522,151.1957362",
          "radius":"500",
          "name":"harbour",
          "language" : "en-IN",
          "types":"food",
          "key":kMapsAPIKey,
           ]
```

I got below issues :

```
{
    "error_message" = "This service requires an API key.";
    "html_attributions" =     (
    );
    results =     (
    );
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a API key to use this service heres a link to get the API key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

the key you used in the params is not a valid key

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0, try out this function to find nearby spot

```
func nearbysearchWithTypeApiCall(){
         key = "Your_Map_API_Key"
         location = "22.2082,70.3807"
         type = "food"

         url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location)&radius=5000&key=\(key)&type=\(type)"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let dicData  = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                self.arrData = dicData["results"] as! NSArray
                print(self.arrData)
                print(self.arrData.count)
                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```